# Web API Post from other domain and computers

Tags: javascript, .net, post, web, get

I have created a new Web-API based asp.net.

If I understood right, you can't POST/GET from other domains.

I need to give this web API to my friends, who use php/javascript/andriod/iphone and be able to allow them to POST/GET to my web API.

Is there any way to get POST/GET with a user/password or something like that?

Comment: What version of web api are you using?

Comment: how can i check? visual studio 2013 if it helps

Comment: You can check it in the nuget package manager

Comment: I i think i am in the newst version probly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note I am assuming that you are using webapi 2.2

This is what I would do. Firstly, follow this tutorial on creating a individual accounts in web api:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

This will allow your users to register with your api and will store credentials securely. You can then use the Authorize attribute on your controller or individual methods (depending on what you want to achieve).

Once a user is registered it can request an access token from the Token endpoint by passing in the username and password (in production ensure you use https). Once a token is received, you can store this client side and send it up with the headers of the request.

So on to CORS. Once you are done with above you can set the server to allow all cross domain from any source, using and verbs by doing the following:

Using the nuget package manage console issue the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors -Version 2.1.0
```

In your startup class (usually Startup.cs) add the following line:

```
 app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

If you want to to be more selective you can create your own custom policy.

NOTE:
It is worth noting that the browser will only issue a pre-flight request (OPTIONS) if the request is NOT deemed simple. A request that is *not simple* is defined as follows:

- It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
  to send request data with a Content-Type other than
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
  text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the
  server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is
  preflighted.
- It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)

(see here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

That should be it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

for .NET Web API

```
set WebAPI basic authentications.
Articles in this issue
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

set WebAPI allow cross domain.
    Aricles in this issue
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Example Get javascript AJAX adding this line

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(username + ':'+password);
},
```

btoa library is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Comment: Thanks, looking forowed more answers.